# Not able to delete LDAP entry

Tags: java, ldap

I want to delete a LDAP entry with its DN in java. I have the code below for that:

```
private void deleteUserAssociations(String customer) throws Exception {

    DirContext ctx = null;
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    NamingEnumeration results = null;

    if (customer != null) {
        ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
        SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
        controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
        results = ctx.search("", "(customer=" + customer+ ")", controls);
        while (results.hasMore()) {
            SearchResult searchResult = (SearchResult) results.next();
            String NameSpaceToDelete = searchResult.getNameInNamespace();
            LdapContext ctxTemp = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
            Control[] tdCtls = new Control[]{new TreeDeleteControl()};
            ctxTemp.setRequestControls(tdCtls);
            ctxTemp.destroySubcontext(NameSpaceToDelete);
            ctxTemp.close();
        }

    }
}
```

The method takes a customer ID to delete, searches the entry in the LDAP and tries to delete that with Tree Delete Control. The Tree Delete Control class is as below:

```
class TreeDeleteControl implements Control 
{
  public byte[] getEncodedValue() {
    return new byte[] {};
  }

  public String getID() {
    return "1.2.840.113556.1.4.805";
  }

  public boolean isCritical() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Problem: The code runs without any error/exception but it does not delete any of the entry. After the execution of the code, I could see all the customers from a LDAP browser (JXplorer).

Please help.

Comment: Did the code find any entries? And surely a method called `deleteUserAssociations()` should delete the associations, not the customers the user is associated with? I suspect you've misunderstood the requirement here.

Comment: In fact you would never cacth me deleting a customer from any database.

Comment: The deletion operation is actually to remove the association between accounts and usernames so that the same account can be reused for other user names. This is related to testing where an account needs to be reused for different user names. The search operation does find entries in 4 different places and we need to remove all of them.